# Simple Prolog pattern patching

Tags: prolog

So if I have something like `[(a,b,c,d)]` and I wish to remove the ()s (in the whole list there will only be one set of parentheses - immediately after the '[' and before the ']'), how come my rule: `curly_for_square( [(C)], [C] ).` doesn't work?  Seems like it should but I'm sure there's a simple reason!!

Comment: Can you show the rest of your procedure? What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Hey, I was thinking I could just pattern match and just use one clause i.e. one line like I gave above.  So if I had something like `:-curly_for_square([(a,b,c)],C).` then I would like `C=[a,b,c]` i.e. with the ()s removed but my incorrect clause just gives `C=[(a,b,c)]` i.e. the same as before :S.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure exactly what `[(a,b,c,d)]` is, but I suspect it's equivalent to `[ ','(a, ','(b, ','(c, d))) ]`, using the infix comma operator three times, since there's no functor taking those four arguments.

If you absolutely must use that syntax, maybe something like this would help convert to an ordinary list:

```
decomma( List, [Head | TailOut] ) :- List = [','(Head,TailIn)], !,
    decomma( [TailIn], TailOut ).
decomma( [Term], [Term] ).
```

Comment: Thanks that's very close to what I want :).  However, do you know why it's making a list with a bar (|) showing that the last element is a a tail?

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but the bar `|` is used to add things before a list.  So if `X=[3,0]` then `[1,5|X]=[1,5,3,0]`.  If you used a comma instead of bar, you get a list within list: `[1,5,X]=[1,5,[3,0]]`.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for not being clear.  All I meant was `decomma([(a,b,c)],X)` gives `X=[a,b|c]` which is correct but I find that predicates such as `last/2` don't manage to get the `c` element when the bar is present.  However, predicates such as `last/2` does get `c` on the list `[a,b,c]` i.e. without the `|`.  Any ideas how to alter decomma/2 to not give a bar in its output?  Hope I've been more clear!

Comment: Yeah, I tried it myself and discovered what you meant.  (Earlier today I didn't have access to a Prolog interpreter and was partly guessing.)  My base case was off.  Added some brackets and fixed it.

Comment: Whoa, nice one for doing that without an interpreter!!  Yeh, I fixed it too in the end :).

Answer (score 0):

To convert back and forth between [a,b,c, ...] and (...(((a,b),c) ... )

```
flatten(X, H, T) :- var(X), !, H = [X|T].
flatten((A,B), H, T) :- !,
 flatten(A, H, X),
 flatten(B, X, T).
flatten(X, [X|T], T).

unflatten([X], X) :- !.
unflatten([A,B|Cs], F) :- unflatten([(A,B)|Cs], F).
```